# What is wrong with my computer

Tags: display

So today I turned on my computer as usual and this happened:

1. BIOS screen was wrong resolution and all blurry.
2. The grub boot menu was also in the wrong resolution. It is supposed to be 1600×900 but appeared to be in 1024×768.
3. I thought something is wrong and booted into Ubuntu to see if I could somehow figure out what was happening
4. A couple of seconds into the boot and the fans starts whirring like crazy. The noise is very audible and disturbing. I am on the maroon/reddish Ubuntu boot screen.
5. A few more seconds in and the display essentially started hallucinating like this:

[image: My computer hallucinates]

At this point I am majorly creeped out. Fans are still spinning and the display has been static for about a minute or two. What is wrong with my computer.

Internals of the computer:

- Intel DH61BF motherboard
- i3-3210 processor (I know it's old but it works)
- Nvidia GT710 GPU
- A rather old Samsung hard drive 500GB.
- A Samsung 2033s monitor. Which has been to the repairs once because it's power circuit failed.

So I tried booting up windows. Windows, however, doesn't even make it past the boot screen. I have Windows 7 on the computer. Windows 7 also does not boot up properly but shows an XP style Boot Screen and then blacks out at which point I simply power of the machine.

Comment: If the monitor has been repaired, my inclination would be to look there first.  The BIOS screen being wrong means there's a basic hardware problem.  I'm just guessing that the computer is getting bad or missing information from the monitor about it's resolution.  The first thing to test would be to plug that monitor into another computer and a known good monitor into this computer (borrow one from a friend or neighbor).  That will tell you whether the problem is in the monitor or the computer.  Try a new or different monitor cable, as a bad cable could be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

From your symptoms, it looks much like hardware issue with the GPU and/or its related components. Software / drivers can't give you maximum fan speed and screen artifacts like that. You'd better visit a laptop repair shop.

Comment: +1 for your diagnosis, but I don't think it's a laptop

Comment: @gronostaj Sorry. I test a lot of desktop hardware everyday, and was mistaken by the GT 710 (I thought it was GT 710M). Usually the weakest in that series that can be found on the market is the GT 730, but I forgot there was an OEM GT 710.